# COCOS2D disappear sprite after animation

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am designing a quiz. Want to animate wrong answer sprite for 2-3 seconds. then it should disappear automatically. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CCFadeOut *fade = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:3];  //this will make it fade
CCCallFuncN *remove = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(removeSprite:)];
CCSequence *seq = [CCSequence actions: fade, remove, nil];
[mySprite runAction:seq];
```

This is the method called by the CCCallFuncN object we alloc'ed above.

```
-(void) removeSprite:(id)sender 
{
[self removeChild:sender cleanup:YES];
}
```

Hope this helps.Cheers!